# Python: How to probe which one is None efficiently?

Tags: python, null

if I have a list of variables `[A, B, C, D]`. How do I **efficiently** find **which** is `None`?

I have

```
if None in (A, B, C, D):
    ValueError("None found.")
```

But it only tests if None is inside it, and can not locate it. I can easily locate it using `for` loop, but please don't do this... What I need is

```
if None in (A, B, C, D):
    # Find where is None
    ValueError("None found in {?}.")
```

Comment: What is your excepted output? The index? It can't be the name since the tuple you are creating does not know them.

Comment: just the index, not the name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Say you have this list:

```
x = [3, 5, None, 2, None]
```

If you want the first None:

```
x.index(None)
```

Outputs `2`, index of the first leftmost `None`.

If you want all indices of `None`s:

```
[i for i, v in enumerate(x) if v is None]
```

Outputs `[2, 4]`, indices of all `None`s in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index instead of a loop:

```
(A, B, C, D).index(None)


print((1, None, 2, 1).index(None))
>> 1
print((1, 2, None, 1).index(None))
>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it also with list comprehension:

```
data = [3, 1, 2, None, 2, None]

print ([i for i in range(len(data)) if data[i]==None])
```

output:

```
[3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Use the fact that sequences have an `index` method to do your search:

```
mylist = [A, B , C, D]
try:
    index = mylist.index(None)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    raise ValueError(f'None found in {index}')
```

If you want to report a name rather than an index, you can use a sequence for reverse lookup:

```
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
raise ValueError(f'None found in {names[index]}')
```